# How to implement session token in PHP backend with angularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, session, token

I'm working with angularJS and PHP backend application,I manage to apply authentication,but when applying session, I get this error: Undefined index: token in select.php file. How can I solve this problem please!

login.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $data    = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
    if (count($data) > 0) {
        $Email    = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->Email);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->password);
        $query    = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE (EmailClient = "' . $Email . '" AND   password= "' . $password . '")';
        $q        = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0) {
            $token = md5($Email . time() . "51395+81519851");
            $query = "UPDATE client SET token = '" . $token . "' WHERE EmailClient = '" . $Email . "'";
            mysqli_query($connect, $query);
            $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true;
            $_SESSION["token"]     = $token;
            $result['message']     = 'Logged In';
            $result['email']       = $Email;
            $result['token']       = $token;
            $resultstring          = json_encode($result);
            $resultstring          = str_replace("null", '""', $resultstring);
            echo $resultstring;
            exit;
        }
        $result['message'] = 'The username or password are incorrect!';
        $resultstring      = json_encode($result);
        $resultstring      = str_replace("null", '""', $resultstring);
        echo $resultstring;
        exit;
    }
?>
```

select.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
    $output  = array();
    $query   = "SELECT Name,Adresse FROM client WHERE token = '" . $_SESSION['token'] . "'";
    $result  = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $output[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: why don you use json webtokens  https://www.sitepoint.com/php-authorization-jwt-json-web-tokens/

Comment: I reead many tutorials about it, and I tried to apply it but I did not succeed